# Move files from subfolders to a parent folder

Tags: directory, subdirectory

I already searched but I dind´t find a script to do what I need. Need help:

I have the situation:

- Parent Folder 1

  - [file 1]
  - [file 2]
  - [subfolder 1]

    - [file 5]
    - [file 6]
- Parent Folder 2

  - [file 7]
  - [file 8]

    - subfolder 2

      - [file 7]
- Parent Folder 3

  - Subfolder 3

    - Subfolder 4

      - Subfolder 5

        - [File 8]

I just need to eliminate all subfolders and move files to parent. I already tested a script in .bat file,  worked, but it need to be one by one parent folder. I it´s hundreds of parents folders.

I mean: I just need first level to keep strtucture.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

`:loop for /d %%D in (%1\*) do (move "%%D\*" %1\ && rmdir "%%D") SHIFT set PARAMS=%1 if not %PARAMS%!==! goto loop`

I just dragNdrop my folders and works. BUT....

Only works with first level of subfolder. I need to go deep to a few more subfolders levels.

Any ideas to improve this?